# Not able to add a Web reference to a WCF Service library using basicHttpBinding

Tags: wcf

I have two instances of VS2010 running on same machine.One VS instance has a WCF service with basicHttpBinding.
Now as i have read in books, for calling this WCF service with basicHttpBinding, i have to Add a Web reference to it rather than Service Reference.
I ran the project containing the WCF service and from other VS instance try to add a Web reference, this is the URL which i gacve(I got it from WCFClientHost )

```
http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibraryBasicHttpBinding/Service1/mex
```

But i get Http 400 error everytime i try to add the WCF service.
Please let know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: **WHAT** books are you reading? If you have a WCF service - no matter which binding you use - you should use `Add Service Reference`

Comment: @marc_s Actually i tried downloading sample code from www.ThatIndigoGirl.com, but didnt work, so followed this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind which says so.

Comment: @marc_s I am able to make it work by usingService reference rather than Web reference, but when do we we have to use web referecne and also why i am not able to add web referecne in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep two things apart:

- `Add Service Reference` adds a service interface based on the .NET 3.0 and up **WCF runtime**. It supports **all** WCF bindings - including `basicHttpBinding`
- `Add Web Reference` is the old-style, .NET 1.x/2.x method of adding a reference to an ASMX web service ("ASP.NET web service"). This technology is outdated, and has been fully replaced by WCF as of .NET 3.0. ASMX only ever supported what is more or less equivalent to `basicHttpBinding`.

  The ASMX technology is outdated, and you should only ever use this if you really can't make WCF work (but in my 3 years of writing and consuming a plethora of web services, I have never seen such a case) - avoid this unless you absolutely can't make WCF work - for whatever weird reason that might be...

The link you gave to the CodeProject article has a **entirely plain wrong statement** that you need to use `Add Web Reference` for `basicHttpBinding` - that is just plain **NOT TRUE**.